# horizontally scrollable uitableview with delete entry

Tags: uitableview

i am using the uitableview with horizontal scroll table is largere than screen,
and i want to delete the entry from table but default method of deleting is not efficient,because when editable is true the delete button is not shown due to large size of table, if any solution please help on this issue.

Thanks
Dhananjay

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be putting a UITableView within a UIScrollView.

My suggestion is to think about your UI so that the table isn't wider than the screen it is displayed on.

Comment: And what if a table is actually a table with lots of data? Tell the customer which data his users should be able to see? :/

Comment: That would be using a custom UITableViewCell that scrolls, or one that displays a horizontal table. The OP is asking about embedding a tableview in a scrollview which isn't recommended.

Comment: I just reacted to your suggestion to rethink the user interface. Many of us get specs and designs handed to us. There is every incentive for him to fit the data within the screen width because of the limits of the components. You assumed he hadn't tried that. You also assumed he had put the tableview inside a scrollview, which is not what he says. Anyway.